# Template10 Setting Service with Background Tasks

Tags: background-task, template10

Given how useful background tasks are in UWP apps, it would be great if there was an easier way to use the Template10 settings service in background tasks (both in and out of proc tasks) so it could be used for data communication between the app the background task.  I'm trying this out now with an out of proc background task and while it initially appeared to work, the challenge now is that every time a task is fired up, it creates a new blank service (ie it seems to be having a problem with ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings as it seems to be different then what is used in the app).  Is this even really possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK my bad, I coded a bug which result in the same default value being returned each time I tried reading something from the settings and I thought it was just a new initialization of the setting service each time.  Otherwise this is working great which is good given a number of the setting set in the app are for the background task.